# Extract string between delimiters

Tags: ruby, regex

How would one get substrings **between** delimiters/multiple delimiters? For example:

```
sample_string = "00990099"
some_method(sample_string, "9") 
=> ["00"]

sample_string = "00XXX00XX0X00X00"
some_method(sample_string, "X")
=> ["00", "0", "00"]
```

I tried using split, but is there an elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

You need a lookaround regex for this like this:

```
(?<=X)[^X]+(?=X)
```

[RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/MGb3MjmEsH)

In Ruby you can use [`string.scan(regex)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) to get all matches

Comment: It's incorrect for second test string in your Demo link.

Comment: Regex is correct. It is due to multiple lines in demo. [See here again with same regex](http://rubular.com/r/meeO45qVyj)

Comment: hmm. Still the same issue.

Comment: That comment no value unless you explain and demonstrate what the issue is. Take this demo http://rubular.com/r/meeO45qVyj and show what is the issue.

Comment: As a method (as you know): `def some_method(str, c); str.scan /(?<=#{c})[^#{c}]+(?=#{c})/; end`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is pretty elegant:

```
str.split(delim, -1)[1...-1].reject(&:empty?)
```

Unlike anubhava's answer this even works with multi-character delimiters. The `-1` argument for `split` stops it from suppressing trailing null fields, which is needed since you need to know if the string ends with a delimiter or not.

```
class String
  def split_delim delim
    split(delim, -1)[1...-1].reject(&:empty?)
  end
end

"00XXX00XX0X00X00".split_delim "X"
# ["00", "0", "00"]

"splitting this long string is my mission".split_delim "is"
# [" long string ", " my m"]
```

Comment: What's wrong in this? If you have delimiter as `XX` then 3rd `X` will be part of match.

Comment: The positive look-behind is greedy. Add any number of Xs in the first block and it will include all but the first two in the match.

Comment: Don't understand that comment. In any case since this is not part of the posted question I don't want to engage in an academic debate. If there is specific question just for handling **multi-character delimiters** I can give full explanation.

Comment: @anubhava Here is a clearer example: http://rubular.com/r/11WV1hDfrA You could argue that the question is ambiguous, but I would argue that a substring of _only delimiters_ (XXXXXX) should not contain any matches.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other ways:

**1: Trim string and use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan)**

```
def some_method(str, c)
  str.gsub(/^[^#{c}]+|[^#{c}]+$/,"").scan /[^#{c}]+/
end

some_method("00990099", "9")         #=> ["00"] 
some_method("00XXX00XX0X00X00", "X") #=> ["00", "0", "00"] 
some_method("0000", "9")             #=> [] 
some_method("9999", "9")             #=> []
```

**2: Split into groups and use [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)**

```
def some_method(str, c)
  str.gsub(r) split(/(#{c}+)/)
     .each_cons(3)
     .with_object([]) { |(_,s,_),a| a << s unless s =~ /#{c}/ } 
end

some_method("00990099", "9")         #=> ["00"] 
some_method("00XXX00XX0X00X00", "X") #=> ["00", "0", "00"] 
some_method("0000", "9")             #=> [] 
some_method("9999", "9")             #=> []
```

Note that when using [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split), `#{c}+` in the regex must be in a capture group to retain the groups of `c` by which `str` is split.